# Adding arrays in an array C#

Tags: c#, computer-science

Hi I've written a code that solves sudoku puzzles and takes a board like this:

```
int[,] grd = {{ 2, 0, 6, 8, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0 },                         
             { 0, 0, 9, 4, 1, 0, 0, 2, 3 },                          
             { 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6 },                          
             { 0, 0, 5, 0, 4, 0, 0, 7, 8 },                          
             { 7, 6, 0, 0, 8, 9, 4, 1, 0 },                          
             { 0, 8, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 },                          
             { 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 8, 0, 6, 4 },                          
             { 8, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2 },                          
             { 0, 5, 2, 1, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0 }};
```

The board is now filled with a valid sudoku puzzle that the program will solve. I'd like to take input to fill the entire board line by line.
I've come up with this bit of code:

```
string unprocesed_nums = Console.ReadLine();
string[] split_nums = unprocesed_nums.Split(' ');
List<int> nums_list = new List<int>();
int nums;
foreach (string s in split_nums)
{
    if (Int32.TryParse(s, out nums))
    nums_list.Add(nums);
 }
    int[] board = nums_list.ToArray();
```

So now I have one array called board, however, I need eight more of them. Is there a fast way to get eight more and then replace the current values in grd with the values I input?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? Do you really plan on sitting at the keyboard and typing these numbers in?

Comment: It's only 81 numbers shouldn't take more than a minute a piece.

Comment: I would suggest that the user could input the numbers into a file, which would be far easier since he could could cut/paste/delete/insert/etc. using all the features of a text editor. Your program could then read from the file much more easily than handling console input. This would also make it a heck of a lot easier to test your application.

Comment: That would also work nicely thanks for the good suggestion.